# How do you set the transparent property of a SCNMaterial object?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

By default the [transparent property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/1462583-transparent) of SCNMaterial objects is set by the alpha channel of an image, called [aOne](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransparencymode) mode.

However, as PNGs would typically be used for images, but as I understand it do not have separate alpha channels, what should be used?

Other materials properties might be set on a node like:

```
modelNode.geometry?.materials[0].diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "diffuse")
```

But as a PNG and JPEG do not seem to be feasible, the only other format that appears like it might have support is TIF, but TIF files cannot seem to be attached to materials in this way, and I've found little verification they are actually supported.

To add further confusion, [iOS seems to have accidentally introduced some breaking changes for this specific property](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/92671) a few months ago, and I have no way of knowing whether it has been fixed, or it is still broken and the cause of issues.

So, what file format should be used here/how can the transparent property of a material be set? Assuming things are currently  in a functional state at lower level.

Thanks

Comment: "TIF files cannot seem to be attached to materials in this way" I don't have trouble doing that.  What difference does that make whether you use PNG or TIFF images?

Comment: PNG files can be either RGB or RGBA, where A = alpha channel.